# Cannot connect to website hosted on same machine with external IP or URL

Tags: windows, networking, docker, windows-11

I'm hosting a website on my local machine running Windows 11, using a few Docker containers. For about a month everything ran fine and I was able to connect no problem. After not working on it for a few weeks when I came back I can connect to the site 1 time, trying to connect again or refreshing the page makes it load for about 5 minutes until it either times out or occasionally gives a PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR (Chrome, Firefox and Edge all behave the exact same way.) Looking at the logs of the webserver the requests (after the first one) aren't making it to the server at all. Restarting my computer allows me to connect a single time before it breaks again.

When connecting from any other computer or phone from the same network or a different network everything works as expected, it's just the local machine that has the issue and only when using the external IP of my router or the URL of the website. Using 127.0.0.1 or localhost is able to reach the server (but gives errors because its not set up to listen on those?)

I've tried all the simple things I could find on Google like flushing DNS, clearing cache/cookies, disabling firewalls and antivirus, changing the ports the server is using but nothing helped.

I'm guessing some Windows update broke something but being able to connect a single time per computer restart makes no sense to me. Restarting just the docker containers doesn't help.

If anyone has any insight or suggestions on what I could try it would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: I don't know if mine supports that but if it doesn't wouldn't that cause other computers on the same network to have the same problem? And why would it suddenly break after a month of working fine?
edit: digging around in the routers setting more, it does support NAT loopback.